# JDBC - Get Sequence CURRVAL after NEXTVAL was used by a Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, triggers, sequence

I use Oracle DB V10.2.0.1.0 for my project, along with Java as the server. I am trying to add data into a few tables only through the code, but it requires using the same sequence value.

I have a sequence which represents the `T_GROUP` table's ID named `GROUP_SEQ`.
(Increment by: 1, Min_Value: 1, Max_Value: 999999999999999999999999, Cache Size: 20, Cycle: No, Order: No).

Said GROUP_SEQ is incremented by a trigger once I enter a new group into the database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GROUP_TRIGGER2
BEFORE INSERT ON T_GROUP for each row
begin
 SELECT GROUP_SEQ.nextval
 INTO :new.ID
 from dual;
END;
```

In my code, I performed `addGroup()` function in my code which *successfully* adds a new group along with the right `GROUP_SEQ` value, however when I try to get the `currval` it fails, because I did not use nextval on it's own, and I get this exception:

```
ORA-08002: sequence GROUP_SEQ.currval is not yet defined in this session
```

Even though I did define it in the trigger. Happens the same if I run the same commands through the SQLplus cmd.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thou hath disobeyed The First Commandment of Oracle, which is: "Thou Shalt Specify Thy Schema, Or Suffer Eternal Damnation; Upon Thy Head Shall Fall Serpents, And Frogs, And Divers Other Reptiles And Amphibians - Yea, Even Upon Thy Head Shall Fall TOADS". Coincidence? I think *NOT!!!!* :-)

Comment: Do you use a connection pool in java server ?

Comment: @krokodilko I'm not sure - I'm using aa singleton to get a single connection through the `DriverManager.getConnection()` function of `java.sql.DriverManager` after I register my driver. I suppose it does use connection pool in the background, but I have not made a pool of my own

Comment: @krokodilko Brilliant, thanks for the enlightenment

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

The problem was indeed the connection I was using - there was a place where I used `getConnection` again and thus had a different session.

Thanks @krokodilko

Answer (score 0):

If you have data to insert into multiple tables then write a stored procedure to do the DML for all the tables in one go:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_group(
  in_column_a IN  T_GROUP.COLUMN_A%TYPE,
  in_column_b IN  T_GROUP.COLUMN_B%TYPE,
  out_id      OUT T_GROUP.ID%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO T_GROUP (
    id,
    column_a,
    column_b
  ) VALUES (
    GROUP_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
    in_column_a,
    in_column_b
  )
  RETURNING id INTO out_id;

  INSERT INTO other_table (
    id
  ) VALUES (
    out_id
  );
END;
/
```

In almost all cases, you do not need to use triggers.